# New icons come up as default file icon in El Capitan

Tags: macos, icon

I'm not able to properly set icons, I've tried with *.icns and *.pngs.

I'm on a El Capitan, MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)

Does this seem familiar to anyone?

[image]

EDIT: I should mention I don't want to [disable any security](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/changing-icons-on-os-x-el-capitan.1894403/)

Comment: You are supposed to copy and paste the actual picture of the icon not drag and drop the file there.

Comment: You can actually do both (or in my case, can't actually do either :P )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try opening the icon in Safari then dragging it from there.

[image: Dragging the image from Safari]

Comment: I'm very surprised but it worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear. I remembered having this problem back in 10.6 so it's definitely not something new!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the icon using [Liteicon](http://freemacsoft.net/liteicon/).

It's a simple application solely able to change icons for applications and some system icons. And if you are changing icons for several applications it should be a simpler and faster way to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately Liteicon doesn't play well with El Capitan :(
https://github.com/tinalatif/flat.icns/issues/216

Comment: The problem you're linking too only applies to system apps - which the app in your example (Spotify) isn't - so that should work for you.

Comment: Ok, I guess its an option. For me _personally_ I'm looking for a fix to OSX rather than an app as its just a single icon I want to change. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: However if you are trying to change system apps icons I don't believe that can be done anymore (neither manually or with Liteicon) because of the new security settings referenced in your github link.

Comment: Yeah sounds like this is just a bug. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

In El Capitain you have to: 
1. Open the "new" image you want to set as folder icon on Preview
2. Select the image from the window
3. Copy/Paste in the Get Info folder Icon
Worked for me :)[image]

Comment: This method is analogous to clicking and dragging an image on the _Get Info_ icon (which should also work for you). Unfortunately on my system, this does not work.